# Sencha allowBlank config property is not applying for TextField widget

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I am using sencha version 6.5.0.180 .I have textField widget in grid and need to make it mandatory.When configuring this widget i have configured 'allowBlank' property with false,but it's not reflecting.Am I doing something wrong

```
{
            xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
            text: 'Applicant Name',
            dataIndex: 'applicantName',
            width: '17%',
            widget: {
                completeOnEnter: false,
                xtype: 'textfield',
                margin: '0 0',
                allowBlank: false,
                maxLength: 100,
                enforceMaxLength: true,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

allowBlank: false tells the validator that the field should not be empty. So you have to validate your field with isValid() or validate(). So it throws an error if the field is blank

Comment: other validations in it are working like maxLength, enforceMaxLength. Only this is not working

Comment: is allowOnlyWhitespace false too in your config?

Comment: Nope am not using that :(

Comment: Can you post a screen of the grid? Do you click a button to save the textfield or whats the plan?

Answer (score 0):

That's weird... have you tried passing your textfield a "validator" function instead ? Something like this :

```js
{
  xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
  text: 'Applicant Name',
  dataIndex: 'applicantName',
  width: '17%',
  widget: {
    completeOnEnter: false,
    xtype: 'textfield',
    margin: '0 0',
    allowBlank: false,
    maxLength: 100,
    enforceMaxLength: true,
    validator: function (val) {
      return Ext.isEmpty(val) ? 'Applicant name is required' : true;
    }
  }
}
```